# H2: JdbcSQLException: This CLOB or BLOB reference timed out

Tags: java, jdbc, h2

Upon using h2 in java (calling `getBytes` function) I'm getting the following error. Google didn't get me anywhere. I wonder if anyone has clues what's going on.

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: This CLOB or BLOB reference timed out: "533668/-3" [90039-190]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.store.LobStorageMap.getInputStream(LobStorageMap.java:287)
    at org.h2.value.ValueLobDb.getInputStream(ValueLobDb.java:384)
    at org.h2.value.ValueLobDb.getBytesNoCopy(ValueLobDb.java:318)
    at org.h2.value.ValueLobDb.getBytes(ValueLobDb.java:304)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.getBytes(JdbcResultSet.java:1059)
    at edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp.srl.caches.SentenceDBHandler$1.next(SentenceDBHandler.java:214)
```

Comment: Could you add a code example?

Answer (score 1):

This error message can occur if you have a long running transaction for instance. You can increase the timeout by setting the LOB_TIMEOUT property on the database connection.

> Database setting LOB_TIMEOUT (default: 300000, which means 5 minutes).
>   The number of milliseconds a temporary LOB reference is kept until it times out. After the timeout, the LOB is no longer accessible using this reference.

https://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/engine/DbSettings.html#LOB_TIMEOUT